# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10 in app-debug.apk

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I implemented a google sign in. It works fine when I run the app from the android studio. I generated an apk to debug in another device. Now, when I try to log in with google I get following error:

```
 com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.bookaholic.shahad.bookaholicbd.activities.HomeActivity.onActivityResult(HomeActivity.java:190)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7638)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4515)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1779)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

But it works fine if I run from the Android studio. I added SHA-1 fingerprints and package name to my Firebase project. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: try to generate and install the release `apk` if you are trying to run in an other device.

Comment: @Lal I tried it. But it did not work either